# Expresiones constantes para detectar la presencia y valor de macros

Tags: c++, macros, constexpr

Estoy haciendo grandes esfuerzos por traducir las macros de mis proyectos a expresiones constantes que puedan ser usadas con `if constexpr`. De momento he conseguido resultados casi satisfactorios haciendo algunos trucos con macros, empiezo definiendo unas macros para transformar valores a texto:

```
#define STRINGIFY(X) #X
#define TO_STRING(X) STRINGIFY(X)
```

Estas macros se comportan de manera *sorprendente* al pasar definiciones existentes o inexistentes, por ejemplo el siguiente código:

```
std::cout << TO_STRING(_DEBUG) << '\n';
```

Muestra `_DEBUG` si la macro homónima NO está definida, mientras que si está definida muestra el valor de la macro. El tipo del valor resultante será siempre un literal de texto (debido al [operador `#` de la macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) `STRINGIFY`). Uso este truco para crear el siguiente enumerado:

```
template <int SIZE>
constexpr bool b(const char (&definition)[SIZE])
{
    return definition[0] != '_';
}

enum operating_system : bool
{
    iOS     = b(TO_STRING(__APPLE__)),
    Windows = b(TO_STRING(__MINGW32__)),
    Linux   = b(TO_STRING(__linux__)),
};
```

Con este *truco*, las macros que estén definidas tendrán valor verdadero mientras que las que no estén definidas el valor contrario, por ello puedo escribir el siguiente código con `if constexpr` en lugar de con `#ifdef`:

```
int main()
{
    if constexpr (operating_system::Windows)
    {
        // Cosas especificas de Windows
    }
    else if constexpr (operating_system::iOS)
    {
        // Cosas especificas de iOS
    }

    // Cosas independientes de sistema operativo.

    return 0;
}
```

No me gusta el tener que delegar en una función auxiliar para traducir los valores (la función `b`), pero es un mal menor. El mayor problema de este sistema es que sólo es capaz de detectar la *presencia* de macros que empiecen por guion bajo (`_`), da falsos positivos para macros cuyo valor sea algo que empiece con guion bajo (`_`) y el valor de la macro se pierde por completo ya que no existe una función calculable en tiempo de compilación que pase texto a numero (ninguno de mis intentos ha tenido éxito).

Por ello las siguientes macros (evidentemente) no actúan como es de esperar:

```
#define _DEBUG 0
#define DRIVERS _09072007

template <int SIZE>
constexpr int i(const char (&definition)[SIZE])
{
    return definition[0] != '_'; // que poner aqui?...
}

enum stuff : int
{
    cpp_version     = i(TO_STRING(__cplusplus)),
    debug_enabled   = i(TO_STRING(_DEBUG)),
    drivers_version = i(TO_STRING(DRIVERS)),
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "C++ version: "     << stuff::cpp_version << '\n'
              << "Modo debug: "      << stuff::debug_enabled << '\n'
              << "Drivers version: " << stuff::drivers_version << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> C++ version: 1
> Modo debug: 1
> Divers verson: 0
> ```

Cuando lo ideal sería haber mostrado:

> ```
> C++ version: 201500
> Modo debug: 0
> Divers verson: _09072007
> ```

Dado que `__cplusplus` tiene un valor numérico que no empieza con guion bajo (`_`), obtiene el valor `1`. A la macro `_DEBUG` le pasa lo mismo: tiene valor `0`, que sería como considerar que no estamos en *modo debug* pero obtiene el valor `1`. Sucede al contrario con la macro `DRIVERS`, que al empezar con guion bajo obtiene el valor `0`.

#### Pregunta.

¿Existe alguna manera de conseguir la salida deseada? Sería necesario como mínimo una `constexpr` que pase literales de texto a número.

#### ¿Qué he intentado?.

He intentado una función recursiva, pero indexar un literal de texto no es una expresión constante (incluso con índices conocidos en tiempo de compilación) .

```
constexpr int power10(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;

    return 10 * power10(n - 1);
}

template <int SIZE>
constexpr int v(const char (&definition)[SIZE], int INDEX)
{
    // error: 'definition' no es una expresion constante
    constexpr char c = definition[INDEX];


    if (INDEX >= 0)
    {
        if constexpr (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            return v(definition, INDEX - 1) + (power10(SIZE - INDEX - 2) * (c - '0'));
        }
        else
        {
            return 0 + v(definition, INDEX - 1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

template <int SIZE>
constexpr int f(const char (&definition)[SIZE])
{
    return v(definition, SIZE - 2);
}

enum operating_system : bool
{
    // error: valor de el enumerador para 'iOS' no es una constante integral
    iOS     = f(TO_STRING(__APPLE__)),
    // error: valor de el enumerador para 'Windows' no es una constante integral
    Windows = f(TO_STRING(__MINGW32__)),
    // error: valor de el enumerador para 'Linux' no es una constante integral
    Linux   = f(TO_STRING(__linux__)),
};
```

Comment: La etiqueta "macros" es ambigua, por un lado aquí aún no tiene wiki, por otro aún en [SO en inglés](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256623/what-to-do-about-macros) me parece que no hay un concenso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TO_STRING(X)` únicamente devolverá el nombre `X` si el valor no está definido:

```
std::cout << TO_STRING(__cplusplus) << " " << STRINGIFY(__cplusplus) << '\n'
          << TO_STRING(NO_EXISTO) << " " << STRINGIFY(NO_EXISTO) << '\n';
```

Salida:

```
201500L __cplusplus
NO_EXISTO NO_EXISTO
```

Una primera aproximación que se me ocurre para solucionar parte del problema está en verificar si el nombre tiene un valor asociado:

```
template <int SIZE1, int SIZE2 >
constexpr int i(const char (&definition)[SIZE1],const char (&check)[SIZE2])
{
    return std::strcmp(definition,check) != 0;
}
```

Aunque sinceramente, para estos casos prefiero hacer uso de `auto`:

```
constexpr int i(auto definition, auto check)
{
    return std::strcmp(definition,check) != 0;
}
```

Con esto ya somos capaces de detectar si el nombre ha sido definido o no:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

//#define _DEBUG 0
#define DRIVERS 09072007

#define STRINGIFY(X) #X
#define TO_STRING(X) STRINGIFY(X)
#define PARSE(X) TO_STRING(X),#X

constexpr bool i(auto definition, auto check)
{
    return std::strcmp(definition,check) != 0;
}

enum stuff : bool
{
  cpp_version     = i(PARSE(__cplusplus)),
  debug_enabled   = i(PARSE(DEBUG)),
  drivers_version = i(PARSE(DRIVERS)),
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "C++ version: "     << stuff::cpp_version << '\n'
              << "Modo debug: "      << stuff::debug_enabled << '\n'
              << "Drivers version: " << stuff::drivers_version << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Salida:

```
C++ version: 1
Modo debug: 0
Drivers version: 1
```

El tema de almacenar el valor es algo más complejo, ya que con `constexpr` no se puede utilizar el tipo `std::string` ya que el mismo hace uso de memoria dinámica... le daré una vuelta a este punto para ver si se me ocurre una forma de extraer el valor asociado al nombre.

Este sistema fallará si el nombre y el valor son iguales:

```
#define NO_FUNCIONA NO_FUNCIONA
```

Pero las posibilidades de que esto pase creo que son ridículas.

**EDITO:**

Después de las conversaciones por el chat y de algunas pruebas adicionales he encontrado una posible solución.

Para cada nombre existe una pareja de valores:

- un booleano que indica si el nombre en cuestión está definido o no
- el valor del elemento (a tener en cuenta únicamente si el nombre está definido)

Tu solución más reciente una vez aplicados mis cambios:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int power10(int power)
{
    if (power == 0)
        return 1;

    return 10 * power10(power - 1);
}

template<int SIZE_A, int SIZE_B>
constexpr bool same_literals(const char (&a)[SIZE_A], const char (&b)[SIZE_B])
{
    bool result = false;

    if constexpr( SIZE_A == SIZE_B )
    {
        result = true;
        for (std::int32_t index = 0; result && (index < SIZE_A); ++index)
        {
            result = (a[index] == b[index]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

template <int SIZE_A, int SIZE_B>
constexpr std::int32_t integral_value_or_zero(const char (&a)[SIZE_A], const char (&b)[SIZE_B])
{
    std::int32_t result = 0;

    if ( !same_literals(a, b) )
    {
        for (std::int32_t index = 0; index < SIZE_B; ++index)
        {
            if (b[index] >= '0' && b[index] <= '9')
            {
                result += power10(SIZE_B - index - 2) * (b[index] - '0');
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

template <int SIZE_A, int SIZE_B>
constexpr bool bool_value_or_false(const char (&a)[SIZE_A], const char (&b)[SIZE_B])
{
    return integral_value_or_zero(a,b) != 0;
}

template <int SIZE_A, int SIZE_B>
constexpr const char *string_or_empty(const char (&a)[SIZE_A], const char (&b)[SIZE_B])
{
    if (same_literals(a, b))
        return "";

    return b;
}

enum class Tipos
{
  Entero,
  Cadena,
};

template<int SIZE_A, int SIZE_B, Tipos>
struct TiposTraits;


template<int SIZE_A, int SIZE_B>
struct TiposTraits<SIZE_A, SIZE_B, Tipos::Entero>
{
  static auto Func(const char (&a)[SIZE_A], const char (&b)[SIZE_B])
  { return integral_value_or_zero(a,b); }
};


template<int SIZE_A, int SIZE_B>
struct TiposTraits<SIZE_A, SIZE_B, Tipos::Cadena>
{
  static auto Func(const char (&a)[SIZE_A], const char (&b)[SIZE_B])
  { return string_or_empty(a,b); }
};


#define STRINGIFY(X) #X

#define INTEGRAL_VALUE_OR_ZERO(X) integral_value_or_zero(#X, STRINGIFY(X))
#define BOOL_VALUE_OR_FALSE(X) bool_value_or_false(#X, STRINGIFY(X))
#define STRING_OR_EMPTY(X) string_or_empty(#X, STRINGIFY(X))

#define NEW_PAIR(X,T) \
  std::make_pair(!same_literals(#X,STRINGIFY(X)),\
                 TiposTraits<sizeof(#X),sizeof(STRINGIFY(X)),T>::Func(#X,STRINGIFY(X)))

#define _DEBUG FALSE
#define DRIVERS _09072007

enum stuff : int
{
    cpp_version     = INTEGRAL_VALUE_OR_ZERO(__cplusplus),
    debug_enabled   = INTEGRAL_VALUE_OR_ZERO(_DEBUG),
    drivers_version = INTEGRAL_VALUE_OR_ZERO(DRIVERS),
    test = INTEGRAL_VALUE_OR_ZERO(test),
};

namespace properties
{
  const std::string cpp_version = STRING_OR_EMPTY(__cplusplus);
  const std::string debug_enabled = STRING_OR_EMPTY(_DEBUG);
  const std::string drivers_version = STRING_OR_EMPTY(DRIVERS);
  const std::string test = STRING_OR_EMPTY(test);

  auto const Cpp_version    = NEW_PAIR(__cplusplus,Tipos::Cadena);
  auto const Driver_version = NEW_PAIR(DRIVERS,Tipos::Entero);
  auto const dummy          = NEW_PAIR(dummy,Tipos::Cadena);

}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Cpp_version has value:    " << std::get<0>(properties::Cpp_version) << '\n'
              << "Cpp_version value:        " << std::get<1>(properties::Cpp_version) << '\n'
              << "Driver_version has value: " << std::get<0>(properties::Driver_version) << '\n'
              << "Driver_version value:     " << std::get<1>(properties::Driver_version) << '\n'
              << "dummy has value:          " << std::get<0>(properties::dummy) << '\n'
              << "dummy value:              " << std::get<1>(properties::dummy) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

La salida que genera el programa ahora será la siguiente:

```
Cpp_version has value:    1
Cpp_version value:        201406L
Driver_version has value: 1
Driver_version value:     9072007
dummy has value:          0
dummy value:
```